# pulseaudio failed to start while ubuntu 21.04 starts with usb microphone plugged-in

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

pulseaudio failed to start if Ubuntu 21.04 runs with usb microphone plugged-in. But pulseaudio starts normally if Ubuntu 21.04 runs without the USB, and it still works fine even the USB plugged-in after the system boots.

The log message from journalctl when pulseaudio failed to start :

```
-- Boot 37de7028dfda47569d03504658160650 --
Dec 11 04:46:09 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: Starting Sound Service...
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server pulseaudio[1967]: No such profile: output:hdmi-stereo
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server pulseaudio[1967]: Failed to initialize daemon due to errors while executing startup commands. Source of commands: /etc/pulse/>
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: Stopped Sound Service.
Dec 11 04:46:10 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: Starting Sound Service...
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server pulseaudio[2087]: No such profile: output:hdmi-stereo
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server pulseaudio[2087]: Failed to initialize daemon due to errors while executing startup commands. Source of commands: /etc/pulse/>
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Dec 11 04:46:11 hirsute-server systemd[1958]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
```

Any ideas? If more info is needed, please don't hesitate to let me know.